# Was Aragorn of interest to the Valar?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I don't know if there is any evidence that says they helped him and his people (aside from Gandalf, aka Olorin), but this has always been a question I think about during the movies. I know it seems odd asking this but I just want to get it out there.

What I mean by interest is: **do they think of him as Middle-earth's salvation and keep tabs on his movements?**

Comment: Aragorn was part Maia (a very small part admittedly) and his wife even more so. According to Letters God himself intervened to push Gollum off the edge into the volcano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always thought Boromir's prophecy alluded to Aragorn and the mentioning of Isildur's sword being re-forged.So if I'm correct then the Valar had a huge interest in Aragorn.

Comment: +1. Who gave the vision would make a good question

Comment: we know there are somethings the valar were not permitted to do, they had to get Eru to intervene to sink numenor and to resurrect Gandalf.

Comment: yes. Tolkien was explicit in one of his letters that it was Eru who sent Gandalf back.

Answer (score 8):

The only indication we have of any special favour Aragorn may have had from the Valar is his lifespan, the longest in a very long time and a throwback to the ancient Númenórean  Kings (emphasis mine):

> It was the pride and wonder of the Northern Line that, though their power departed and their people dwindled, through all the many generations the succession was unbroken from father to son. Also, **though the length of the lives of the Dúnedain grew ever less in Middle-earth, after the ending of their kings the waning was swifter in Gondor**; and many of the Chieftains of the North still lived to twice the age of Men, and far beyond the days of even the oldest amongst us. **Aragorn indeed lived to be two hundred and ten years old, longer than any of his line since King Arvegil; but in Aragorn Elessar the dignity of the kings of old was renewed.**
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix A "Annals of the Kings and Rulers" I "The Númenórean Kings" *(iii) Eriador, Arnor, and the Heirs of Isildur*</sub></sup>

However, whether or not this "special favour" kicks in before or after his ascent to the throne is unknown. During the course of Aragorn's life before he becomes King Elessar, we have no indication that the Valar had any special interest in him.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean he was favored by Eru, not the Valar, as the question is phrased? (this applies to @CarlSixsmith's comment too)

Comment: @Junuxx Not necessarily; we don't actually know who gave the Númenóreans longer life (we know Eönwë taught them some things, but it's not clear if that's related to their extended lifespan), but there seems to be no reason the Valar couldn't have done it. They're not *revoking* the gift of Death, just postponing it

Comment: Also, Aragorn doesn't seem to have lived *that* much longer than his recent forefathers. Appendix A mentions that "in Aragorn Elessar the dignity of the kings of old was renewed", which could suggest a "restoration" of sorts of the original longer life of the line of Elros. Aragorn lived to 190, said to be the oldest since Arvegil, the 5th-to-last king of Arthedain....

Comment: ... There's some evidence that even the Chieftains of the Dúnedain lived well into their 100s, though. Ignoring the ones that died prematurely, the deaths are about 70 years apart right up to Aragorn. Compare that to a typical modern human, with one generation appearing to outlive the next by, say, 40-50 years.